# Calling Secured RESTEasy service from a servlet in JBOSS EAP 6.3

Tags: java, jboss7.x, resteasy

I protected my RESTFul service that is being called form a servlet in web.xml through "security-constraint". But I cannot call this service from servlet when it is protected through "security-constraint", when I comment that out, my service is no more protected and I can call the service from the client. Please suggest a way in which I can protect my service and still call it from the servlet.

SERVICE WAR

```
 ent_securityprefs_empService 
      -src 
         -com.xxxx.channel.employee.service 
            -Employee.java 
            -Employees.java 
            -EmployeeService.java 
         -com.xxxx.channel.employee.service.bean 
            -EmployeeBean.java 
      -WebContent 
        -WEB-INF 
           -beans.xml 
           -jboss-web.xml 
           -web.xml 
      -hello.jsp
```

Employee.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Employee {

    private int empId;
    private String empName;
    private String empAddress;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public String getEmpAddress() {
        return empAddress;
    }
    public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
        this.empAddress = empAddress;
    }

}
```

Employees.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Employees {

    private List<Employee> employee;

    public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(List<Employee> employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

}
```

EmployeeService.java

```
@Produces({ "application/xml" })
@Path("/employee")
public class EmployeeService {

    @Inject
    private EmployeeBean empBean;

    private TreeMap employeeMap = new TreeMap();

    public EmployeeService(){
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.setEmpId(1111);
        employee1.setEmpName("EmployeeOne");
        employee1.setEmpAddress("San Antonio TX");

        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.setEmpId(2222);
        employee2.setEmpName("EmployeeTwo");
        employee2.setEmpAddress("Dallas TX");

        Employee employee3 = new Employee();
        employee3.setEmpId(3333);
        employee3.setEmpName("EmployeeThree");
        employee3.setEmpAddress("Austin TX");

        employeeMap.put(employee1.getEmpId(),employee1);
        employeeMap.put(employee2.getEmpId(),employee2);
        employeeMap.put(employee3.getEmpId(),employee3);

    }

    @GET
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    @Path("/allEmp")
    public Employees getEmployees(){
        List employees = new ArrayList();
        employees.addAll(empBean.getEmployeeMap().values());
        Employees allEmployees = new Employees();
        allEmployees.setEmployee(employees);
        return allEmployees;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathParam("id") int employeeId){
        return (Employee) employeeMap.get(employeeId);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/addEmp")
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    public Employee addEmployee(@FormParam("employeeId")int id, @FormParam("employeeName")String name, @FormParam("employeeAddress")String address){
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpId(id);
        employee.setEmpName(name);
        employee.setEmpAddress(address);
        employeeMap.put(employee.getEmpId(), employee);
        empBean.setEmployeeMap(employeeMap);
        return employee;
    }

}
```

EmployeeBean.java

```
@ApplicationScoped 
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable{ 

private TreeMap employeeMap; 

public EmployeeBean(){ 
employeeMap = new TreeMap(); 
} 

public TreeMap getEmployeeMap() { 
return employeeMap; 
} 

public void setEmployeeMap(TreeMap employeeMap) { 
this.employeeMap = employeeMap; 
} 
}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

      <!-- An application that uses CDI must have a file named beans.xml. 
      The file can be completely empty (it has content only in certain 
      limited situations), but it must be present. -->

</beans>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/Employee</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>ent_securityprefs_empService</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>EmployeeChannel</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint> -->

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Channel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a >Employee Record</a>
</body>
</html>
```

CLIENT WAR

```
ent_securityprefs_emp 
   -src 
      -EmployeeServlet.java 
   -WebContent 
      -WEB-INF 
         -jboss-deployment-structure.xml 
         -jboss-web.xml 
         -web.xml 
   -index.jsp
```

EmployeeServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/EmployeeServlet")
public class EmployeeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/xml");

        try{
            //Initiate a client request using the url as a parameter
            ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:8080/ent_securityprefs_empService/rest/employee/1111");
            request.accept("application/xml");

            //To get the response based on the request
            ClientResponse<String> response = request.get(String.class);

            //Check the HTTP status of the request
            //HTTP 200 indicates the request is OK
            if(response.getStatus() != 200){
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed request with HTTP status: "+response.getStatus());
            }

            //If we get a good response, now let's read it
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getEntity().getBytes())));

            String output;

            //Loop over the br in order to print out the contents
            while((output = br.readLine()) != null){
                pw.println(output);
            }
        } catch(ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            System.err.println(cpe);
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println(ioe);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        pw.close();
    }

}
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="com.xxxx.channel"/>
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

- Note

: This module has all the required dependencies in it. 
jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/Employee</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ent_securityprefs_emp</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>EmployeeChannel</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="EmployeeServlet">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <input type="submit" value="Employee Record" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

SERVER CONFIGURATION FILE

- Note

: I am only adding security-domain part to avoid confusion. This is the security domain to which my service and client are configured to.

standalone-full.xml

```
<security-domain name="Employee" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ha-adds-global.xxxx.com:3268"/>
                            <module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=prodjbsvc,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=NOPOL,dc=eagle,dc=xxxx,dc=com"/>
                            <module-option name="bindCredential" value="XQtU@1lc"/>
                            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="dc=eagle,dc=xxxx,dc=com"/>
                            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=XXXX ALL_CONTRACTORS,OU=GROUPS,OU=SMO,OU=COSAs,DC=eagle,DC=usaa,DC=com))"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=COSAs,dc=eagle,dc=xxxx,dc=com"/>
                            <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                            <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="-1"/>
                            <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```